# 'While' loop counting up

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I am practicing ruby. In one of the exercises, it asks me to try and use a 'while' loop to print the numbers 1 to 50 inclusively. (counting up)
I also have a code that counts down.

```
    i = 50
    while i > 0 do
      print i
      i -= 1
    end
```

anyway you could make the code above counting up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
    $i = 1
    $num = 51

    while $i < $num  do
       print("#$i" )
       $i +=1
    end
```

that would help..

and go to this for more help
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm

Comment: this is not a recommended style to write a loop in ruby. Use n.times {|val| #Do something}

Answer (score 6):

Try Below Simple Ruby Magics :)

```
(1..50).each { |n| puts n }
50.times { |n| puts n }
1.upto(50) { |n| print n }
```

Here counting up is being automatically inside ruby library, so dont worry about it

Comment: This does not use a 'While' loop

Answer (score 1):

Your are counting backwards, from `i = 50` to `1`. You must go from `i = 1` to `50`, increasing `i += 1` on each loop.

Change it to this:

```
i = 1
while i <= 50 do
  print i
  i += 1
end
```

Comment: also how do you print 1 to 50 using a 'for' loop?

Answer (score 1):

Just to help you understand what you typed :

when you type: `i -= 1`, it is the same as typing: `i = i - 1`

when you type : `i += 1`, it is the same as typing : `i = i + 1`

You should then easily understand why, when you want to decrement your variable i, you start by initializing i at 50 (before the while loop starts).
And when you want to increment your variable i, you start by initializing i at 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1):

And a bit simplified:

```
(1..50).each { |number| puts number }
```